# One time retrieving data with Select2 jquery

Tags: json, jquery-select2

I have a problem with the select2 component (jQuery).
I have this as code:

```
        $('#username').select2({
        width: "400px",
        placeholder: "Selecteer 1 of meerder paritaire comités",
        style: "display; inline-block",
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        multiple: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "/Prospect/_LoadParComs/",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            data: function (searchTerm) {
                return {
                    query: searchTerm
                }
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
                return { results: data }
            }
        }
    });
```

Now it works, everytime I click on the htmlelement my data gets called and I see the result. When I click an item the item gets on the htmlelement and ok. But everytime I click the element it goes back to retrieve my data and this takes time, 5 seconds at least.
Isn't it possible to load the data 1 time and work with it ? Without always having to get the data over and over again ?

kind regards

Comment: can't you add a control variable that is initialized with false, and that you update with true when you have the results? Then use it to prevent the next fetch of data.

Comment: and where should I do that ? 
Kind regards